# Looking for the record store from MI: Rogue Nation

Tags: vinyl

The [opening scenes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bk9I3j6LKDY) of Mission Impossible: Rogue Nation feature a vinyl store with lovely old-school decor. Unfortunately, the store is an [invention](http://www.movie-locations.com/movies/m/Mission-Impossible-Rogue-Nation.html), and the location is a laundry in real life.  Is the one in the movie based on a particular, real-world store?  If not, is there a way to locate one very much like it? Most stores I've visited are quite lovely but more modern.

In particular, I'm looking for:

1) a store that looks very similar to the one in the movie (checkerboard tiled floor, brick walls, wooden furniture), with

2) completely enclosed listening booths, like the one that Tom Cruise steps into. A search shows many examples of listening booths but none that are completely enclosed.

[image: mi_vinyl_store]

Comment: Hi Vincent, welcome to the site.  The short answer is yes.  The [vinyl store I went to as a kid](http://www.usedkidsrecords.com/) is still around, although in a different location and still looks much like it did back then (early 90s).  But this question seems ridiculously broad.   Are you asking if there are any stores still like this one, anywhere in the world? Why wouldn't there be?

Comment: @ChrisSunami sorry that I phrased the question so poorly. Let me try to be more specific. 

I wanted to know two seperate things: whether there is 1) a store that looks very similar to the one in the movie (checkerboard tiled floor, brick walls, wooden furniture) and that the one in the movie might have been based off, and 2) completely enclosed listening booths, like the one that Tom Cruise steps into. A [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=record+store+listening+booth) shows many examples of listening booths but none that are completely enclosed.